# django-extra-views and nested formsets

Tags: django, inline-formset

I would like to make use of a nested inline formset using django-extra-views for both create and update.

I can implement a typical (non-nested) inline formset without issue. Here is a basic example of that.

```
# forms.py
class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Product

        # for brevity, assume these fields are defined on the `Product` model
        fields = [
            'name',
            'image',
            'price',
        ]


class VariantForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Variant

        # for brevity, assume these fields are defined on the `Variant` model
        fields = [
            'price_override',
            'shipping_dimensions',
        ]


class InlineVariant(InlineFormSet):
    model = models.Variant
    form_class = VariantForm
    extra = 1
```

And

```
# views.py
class Add(CreateWithInlinesView):
    template_name = "products/add.html"
    model = models.Product
    form_class = forms.ProductForm

    inlines = [
        forms.InlineVariant,
    ]


class Edit(UpdateWithInlinesView):
    template_name = "products/edit.html"
    model = models.Product
    form_class = forms.ProductForm
    context_object_name = "product"

    inlines = [
        forms.InlineVariant,
    ]
```

But, now I want `Stock` to be inline for each `Variant`.

```
# forms.py
class StockForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Stock

        # for brevity, assume these fields are defined on the `Stock` model
        fields = [
            'location',
            'quantity',
        ]


class InlineStock(InlineFormSet):
    model = models.Stock
    form_class = StockForm
    extra = 1
```

How could the views defined above be modified?

There is an existing [django-extra-views issue](https://github.com/AndrewIngram/django-extra-views/issues/6) that asserts this is possible. However, no clear example of how to do it. Someone does suggest to make a custom `formset_class`.

I also found a separate package, [django-nested-admin](https://github.com/theatlantic/django-nested-admin/blob/master/nested_admin/formsets.py), that defines a seemingly generic `NestedInlineFormset` class. Could that be integrated somehow?

I find this really confusing.